# How to use multicol package on A3-sized documents

Tags: spacing, multicol

**Context**

I would like to work with multiple columns (3) on A3-sized sheets of paper. It seems to stop halfway.

**Code**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm, showframe, landscape, a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\lipsum{3}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

**Question**

How can I make it such that it continues while the page is in landscape mode? Ideally I want a column in multicol to stop at the bottom margin of the oriented page (1 cm).

Comment: IN MWE you not insert enough text that it will fulfil one page. Instead of `\lipsum{3}` insert `\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum`.

Comment: `multicols` balances the columns, if you don't want that use `\begin{multicols*}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ah I totally forgot, thank you.

Comment: Try `\lipsum[1-20]` and you'll get the idea ;)